# В конце кода выдает ошибку Invalid syntax

Tags: python

Я только начал изучать программирование и написал программу "калькулятор", но когда я хочу запустить код в терминале выводится ошибка.

Подскажите, что сделать, чтобы программа запустилась?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `:` забыли.............

Comment: Где именно забыл?

Comment: Перестаньте выкладывать код картинками! Для этого есть разметка! Скопируйте из редактора, иначе ваш вопрос будет помечен на удаление

Comment: В тексте ошибки же написано: Line 15, и стрелочкой указано, где.

Comment: В самом начале написано инпут не правильно, знаю, но где отмечено стрелочкой? Вижу что линия 15, но там ведь нет стрелочки

Answer (score 4):

Двоеточие надо добавить вот здесь (я подчеркнул стрелочку и поставил двоеточие там, где оно ожидается)

[image: вот здесь]

Все конструкции, создающие вложенный блок (`if`, `for`, `with`, `while` и т.п.) заканчиваются двоеточием.